# The command "brew uninstall ffmpeg" gives me a permission error

Tags: ffmpeg

I get this Error:

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/libswscale.dylib
```

What is this dylib for ? I upgraded and broke my installation by that (i assume) and tried to uninstall and unlinked. Unlink worked. uninstall gave me the error.

What is the correct procedere ? `sudo brew uninstall ffmpeg` ?

Why did I upgrade ? It worked fine before ...

Comment: Before you do anything else, try running brew doctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libswscale` is the software picture scaler of ffmpeg.

Normally `brew uninstall ...` should work. In all likelihood you installed ffmpeg manually at some point (`sudo make install`) or forced `brew` to install with `sudo` (which brew normally refuses).

In general you should avoid `sudo` with `brew`, but in this case it would be OK to fix the broken stuff:

```
sudo brew uninstall ffmpeg
```

Alternatively `sudo rm` the files `brew` complains about.

Comment: Thanks! How do I know which of these dylibs are dangerous to delete and which will be replaced ? Is there anyway to find out if they are system essential dylibs. As you can see from my questions, I don't know much bout dylibs. Thanks again for the answer

Comment: The system essential dylibs do not reside in `/usr/local` (on OSX). Anyway, assume deleting stuff is dangerous until proven otherwise. Deleting `libswscale` from the `/usr/local` prefix might be somewhat dangerous as other software might link it. You'd know better what software you installed. But at least the system won't use it (`/usr/local/` ;), so you cannot actually brick your system. Properly Re-installing `brew install ffmpeg` after you uninstalled it might be a good idea if you're unsure about other software dependencies.

Comment: PS: You already tried to uninstall it, so I did assume we're already beyond the point of considering if `libswscale` is important for third-party software or not. ;)

Comment: True. But it did not work and than as humans do, I "re" thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiLNqg2IOAQ&feature=youtu.be)
i made this video. install ffmpeg using binaries best way. it comes precompiled with every codec.